# Laravel route with variable in the url

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4, forgot-password, cartalyst-sentry

I am trying to implement the password reset logic. The user gets the link to reset the password in the email. The url looks like

```
http://example.com/reset/resetcode
```

I have the route defined for it:

```
Route::get('reset/{resetcode}', function(){
    return View::make('users.reset_password');
});
```

The form is rendered in the view to submit the `email, new password` etc. For the post of the form I have route defined as:

```
Route::post('reset/{resetcode}', array( 'as' => 'reset', 'uses' => 'UserController@passwordReset'));
```

I grab the `resetcode` from `post route` inside the `passwordReset` controller below

```
public function passwordReset($resetcode)
{ 
    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), UserModel::$rulesPasswordReset);
    if ($validation->passes())
    { 
    try
    {
    // Find the user using the user email address
    $user = Sentry::findUserByLogin(Input::get('email'));

    // Check if the reset password code is valid
    if ($user->checkResetPasswordCode($resetcode))
    {
        // Attempt to reset the user password
        if ($user->attemptResetPassword($resetcode, 'new_password'))
        {
        // Password reset passed
         }
         else
         {
        // Password reset failed
         }
    }
    else
    {
        // The provided password reset code is Invalid
    }
        }
        catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
        {
       echo 'User was not found.';
        }
    }
    else return Redirect::route('reset')->withInput()
    ->withErrors($validation)
    ->with('title', 'resetrequestfailure')
    ->with('message', 'Seems like you made some errors.');
   }
```

**The problem I am having is when I do `Redirect::route` after the validation fails.** I am getting the `resetcode` from the route defined for `post`. When validation fails, the redirect route messes up and I cannot get the `resetcode` the second time. The supposed url of format

```
 http://example.com/reset/8f1Z7wA4uVt7VemBpGSfaoI9mcjdEwtK8elCnQOb
```

becomes

```
http://bcnet.org/reset/%7Bcode%7D
```

It has to do with `/{resetcode}` part of the route and this is variable, so how can I get the correct `resetcode` even after the validation fails meaning that the url remains intact. Or how can I fix it to the appropriate `Redirect::route` after the validation failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `$resetcode` on your return

```
else return Redirect::route('reset', $resetcode)->withInput()
    ->withErrors($validation)
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. I am off today. I will test in detail tomorrow and reply back. Cheers.

Comment: One more thing. Is this `$resetcode` on return getting set on `Route::post('reset/{code}', array( 'as' => 'reset', 'uses' => 'UserController@passwordReset'));` `{code}` part of the post route?